# JS - Как вывести содержимое файла .doc/.docx в браузер?

Tags: javascript, doc

Может есть какие-нибудь бесплатные библиотеки на JS для этого? google doc не предлагать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript

Comment: https://effectiveinc.com/thought-leadership/blogs/generating-downloadable-word-document-browser/

Comment: можно воспользоватся инструментом от Microsoft
`https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=` вот пример https://duoxx.github.io/doc.html

Comment: Есть вот такой сервис от Microsoft: [View Office documents online](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/view-office-documents-online).